# Rule for attribute names starting '__' but enforce PascalCase

Tags: python, pylint

I have some code where I use double underscore for attribute name, but conform to the pascal case standard.

The issue is that I get a warning for: `self.__LastErrorMsg:`

> ConfigurationManager.py:91:8: C0103: Attribute name "__lastErrorMsg" doesn't conform to PascalCase naming style (invalid-name)

The code is:

```
class ConfigurationManager():
    @property
    def LastErrorMsg(self):
        return self.__LastErrorMsg

    def __init__(self):
        self.__LastErrorMsg = ''
```

I know there is a regex override, but I am not sure how I would write it.  Any suggestions or examples would be gratefully welcome.

Comment: This is completely valid Python code. Maybe you should file a bug report to pylint.

Comment: @Adirio: PyLint is not intended to accept all valid Python code. A linter that did that would be pretty useless.

Comment: @user2357112 Isn't the point of the regex override to allow for such cases?  I know if  you look at PEP8 the use of double underscores are discussed.

Comment: @LucyThomas: The regex options are intended to allow custom formatting styles. My comment was just pointing out that PyLint rejecting valid code isn't a PyLint bug.

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry I misunderstood.

Comment: @user2357112 By valid code I mean that `__LastErrorMsg` is PascalCase. If you have checked that you don't have any `__lastErrorMsg` atributes (as the error line suggests that the example you wrote is simplified), then PyLint may be having some issues with double-underscore prepended fields when it shouldn't, and therefore I would consider it a PyLint bug. But double-check that you haven't misspelled `__lastErrorMsg` before.